# How to manage/control font/component size in Javascript Build apps

Tags: codenameone

I found my Javascript build apps's font/control size show differently in different platform, e.g. it show normal in iphone's safari browser, but shown "huge" in android chrome browser.

It also shown bigger font/control in Desktop Chrome Browser, but in desktop is fine, I can just Ctrl+'+' or Crtl+'-' to increase/decrease the control, to make it looks good... should I called it Canvas?

I am putting viewport meta tag as:

```
  <meta name="viewport"
  content="
    height = device-height,
    width = device-width,
    initial-scale = 1.0,
    minimum-scale = 1.0,
    maximum-scale = 1.0,
    user-scalable = no,
    target-densitydpi = device-dpi" />
 <style>
```

I tried to play around the scale value, it just cannot show properly, either oversize or too small compare to browser windows.

Please help.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot to demonstrate the font size issue on android chrome.  I just ran some tests in some of my apps and everything looks fine on Android Chrome.

Comment: After I resent the Javascript build (and upload and lastest built to my server) and reload/clear my Android Chrome cache, the font look ok already. The font problem happen on old Javascript built. But with the lastest build, all is fine. Thank you for your help to clarify.